# Is 80GB too large for a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I am making a table that stores lots of texts. I anticipate needing about 1 million rows. Each row contains one cell that can have as little as 1 page or as much as 200 pages of text. If I get to 1 million rows, the table will be about 80 GB. Is this too big? Will queries be extra slow?

My table is only 20 MB right now, and there aren't any performance issues yet.

My collation is utf8_bin since the texts are in other languages too.

If 80 GB is far too much, I will have to have a separate table for each language, making each table less than 2 GBs.

Comment: When putting that much text into a single field - what kind of queries are you planning for?

Comment: Searching the field's text for specific words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How big is too big for a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406417/how-big-is-too-big-for-a-mysql-table)

Comment: @billyhafiz If searching for all documents with specific words, I suggest you use either some specialized software like lucene or at least build a reversed index for your data.

Comment: Insert 1 million rows and test it.